# IntelliJ IDEA Python plugin - how to make it treat HTML files as Django templates?

Tags: django, intellij-idea, pycharm

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 13 Ultimate edition with its Python plugin. I opened an existing folder containing a Django project (which I had created using Vim) as an IntelliJ project and enabled the Django facet manually on it. However, my HTML files are still being treated as plain HTML files - Django template tags and syntax aren't recognized. I recall that Django templates were automagically recognized by IntelliJ in an earlier project, but can't reproduce it now.

How can I get IntelliJ to recognize my template files as Django templates, please?

Comment: I'd love to know this too.

Answer (score 13):

Here's how I did it on IntelliJ IDEA 14 for Jinja2 templates (similar to Django): `Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Python Template Languages`: Select "HTML files" in the list and choose "Jinga2" for Template Language.

Comment: In IDEA 2016.1.3, I chose "Jinja2" for the Template Language, but my *.html files are still treated as Django templates rather than Jinja2. It only works if I rename the actual files to *.jinja2 (which I don't want).

Comment: @Ilya Semenov   you should set django not jinja2 in `Python Template Languages` as mentioned here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/debugging-django-templates.html